# MS SQL Server на Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, виртуальная-машина, облако

Задался вопросом - как совместить высокую производительность и минимальные издержки? Задача в том, что нужно развернуть MS SQL Server на Azure, но можно это сделать:

1. Как Azure сервис (ресурс), что даст все плюсы облачного решения, но
   за него придется платить отдельно.
2. Как standalone на виртуальной машине (за которую уже платим). Но в
   этом случае быстродействие будет лимитировано выбранным тарифом ВМ.

Может ли кто-то из уважаемых коллег посоветовать какое же из решений выбрать?

Comment: Смотрите по [функционалу](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features) ещё. В Azure SQL, например, не поддерживаются Filestream и CLR.

Comment: @i-one, Filestream точно не понадобится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты Azure SQL и SQL на отдельной VM отличаются не столько производительностью, сколько надежностью и затратами на сопровождение. Не забывайте, что даже на отдельной виртуалке вам придется доплачивать за SQL (хотя Web Edition там дешевый).

Azure SQL

- обеспечивает вам 99.99% аптайм ([SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/sql-database/v1_0/))
- обеспечивает непрерывных бэкап
- полностью снимает необходимость ставить апдейты вручную
- дает доступ к [Query Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817826.aspx) - фоновому сбору статистики о запросах, который в обычном SQL Server есть толко в Enterprise Edition.

SQL на одной VM под SLA не попадает вообще. [SLA для VM начинает действовать](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_0/) только в рамках Availability Set - минимум двух машин. На каждой из которых вам придется поднять SQL Server, и настроить между ними синхронизацию.

---

Но это в теории. На практике одиночные машины на Azure достаточно стабильны. Но тем не менее - при использовании одиночной VM вам стоит настроить как минимум

- автоматический бэкап - настраивается через управление VM в портале, но для Web Edition требует дополнительных телодвижений на самой VM
- регулярные апдейты - так же настраиваются через портал

и быть готовым к ребутам виртуалки при установке обновлений.

---

По быстродействию - вам стоит помнить, что и на SQL Azure, и на VM есть разные лимиты, в которые вы можете упереться:

- Память. На VM - это просто объем доступной памяти. На SQL Azure - какой-то неизвестный лимит ([около 9Gb для P1/P2, и около 512 Mb для Standard, судя по тестам](https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/11/11/azure-sql-database-memory-limits-by-service-tier/))
- CPU - Явный (измеряемый и поднимаемый) лимит и на SQL Azure и на VM.
- Data IO - лимит на скорость чтения. Явный лимит на SQL Azure, совершенно неявный на VM - т.к. зависит от скорости Storage, который дико медленный в Standard.
- Log IO - лимит на скорость записи - те же ограничения, что и у Data IO

В целом стоит быть готовым к тому, что и SQL Server на VM, и Azure SQL будут достаточно медленными по производительности в совсем бюджетном варианте. Если у вас нет админа - то выбирайте Azure SQL - обойдется дешевле. Если есть админ - выбирайте то, во что вписываетесь по бюждету.

В любом случае, переехать с одного варианта на другой можно в несколько кликов.